# Power BI cumulative count with multiple condition

Tags: powerbi

Did anyone know how to convert RunningCount into Power bi Dax ? 
I test on RunningTotal, Rankx but seems not working. 
The [year] is just a text column not in Datetime format.

I still new on this and not sure if my explain is good enough or not. Sorry for any inconvenient cause.

I try to create measure/ calculation column in power bi from the formula below. 
I need the count by Year, break by column like product, customer, rate and category.

Comment: Hello, you should try and add more information to improve your post. Try adding some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I get into my solution, there are a few assumptions I had to make:

1. The "Year" column is supposed to be years, and not five digit numbers. So in my data I dropped the second "2" in each (i.e. "20213" -> "2013").
2. You may have another column in your data to break ties, but given the data you provided, there is no way to rank the first and third lines (they both have product ABC and year 2003).

Given those assumptions, here is my solution...

First, here is what my data looks like. I added an ID column so that we can see every row, even duplicates.

[image: Data]

From there, you can simply add a new column with the following formula.

```
Running Count = 
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            'Data',
            [ProductName] = EARLIER([ProductName]) &&
            [Customer] = EARLIER([Customer]) &&
            [Seller] = EARLIER([Seller]) &&
            [Year] <= EARLIER([Year])
        )
    )
```

The [`EARLIER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/earlier-function-dax) function is being used to specify a ProductName, Customer, etc. from the row of the table to be used in the filtering of the data. Once we have the data filtered, we can simple count the number of rows.

The final result looks like this. As noted in my second assumption, there is no way to break ties, so my numbers are slightly off from what you have in your screenshot

[image]

Comment: I tested but it showing 'EARLIER/EARLIEST refers to an earlier row context which doesn't exist.'

Comment: @user3522363 Are you trying to create a measure or column? The formula I provided will only work for a column. If you want it to be a measure, it will have to be tweaked a little.

Comment: @user3522363 Are you creating the column on the table that holds the data?