# How would a formula using EARLIER be changed to work as a measure?

Tags: dax

My question is very similar to the one in this post: [PowerBI DAX - Identifying first instance based on multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55286495/powerbi-dax-identifying-first-instance-based-on-multiple-criteria). I have a streaming dataset with lots of "jobs" and I am interested in filtering out duplicates based on the job name, pass/fail status, attempt number, and another identifier we can call "module". There is a unique time stamp column that I thought I could utilize as an index. I understand that in order to use the EARLIER function I need to have 2 levels of ROW context and that in the previously mentioned post a calculated column was used. My issue is very similar except with a streaming dataset, so I can only use measures. I tried wrapping the entire formula in a SUMX to achieve 2 levels of row context but that is yielding results that don't make sense. Here is the formula as it looks now:

```
Running Count = 
SUMX( RealTimeData,
        COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                RealTimeData,
                RealTimeData[Status] = "Failure" &&
                RealTimeData[AttemptNumber] = 4 &&
                RealTimeData[Study] = EARLIER(RealTimeData[Study]) &&
                RealTimeData[Module] = EARLIER(RealTimeData[Module])&&
                RealTimeData[StartDate] <= EARLIER(RealTimeData[StartDate])
            )
        ) 
)
```

In the context of the above linked question, my desired output would look like this:

| ID | Product | Purchase Date | First Instance? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1/1/2019 | 1 |
| 2 | B | 1/2/2019 | 1 |
| 1 | B | 1/5/2019 | 1 |

I like the idea of doing this using a TRUE/FALSE flag but obviously that won't work with SUMX. Am I overlooking some easier way of doing this with filters perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be easier to start from scratch than try to adjust the pattern in that question. In general though, you can use variables to a similar effect.

For example,

```
CalcCol =
SUMX (
    FILTER ( Table1, Table1[Col1] = EARLIER ( Table1[Col1] ) ),
    Table1[Col2]
)
```

can be rewritten as

```
CalcColVar =
VAR CurrentCol1 = Table1[Col1]
RETURN
    SUMX ( FILTER ( Table1, Table1[Col1] = CurrentCol1 ), Table1[Col2] )
```

but writing this a measure you'd need to change it to

```
Meas =
VAR CurrentCol1 = SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[Col1] )
RETURN
    SUMX ( FILTER ( ALL ( Table1 ), Table1[Col1] = CurrentCol1 ), Table1[Col2] )
```

but this would be more efficiently computed as

```
Meas = CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table1[Col2] ), ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[Col1] ) )
```

---

For your particular measure, you probably want something like this:

```
Running Count =
VAR DateStart = SELECTEDVALUE ( RealTimeData[StartDate] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( RealTimeData ),
        RealTimeData[Status] = "Failure",
        RealTimeData[AttemptNumber] = 4,
        ALLEXCEPT ( RealTimeData, RealTimeData[Study], RealTimeData[Module] ),
        RealTimeData[StartDate] <= DateStart
    )
```

or

```
First Instance? =
VAR DateStart = SELECTEDVALUE ( RealTimeData[StartDate] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        ISEMPTY ( RealTimeData ),
        RealTimeData[Status] = "Failure",
        RealTimeData[AttemptNumber] = 4,
        ALLEXCEPT ( RealTimeData, RealTimeData[Study], RealTimeData[Module] ),
        RealTimeData[StartDate] < DateStart
    )
```

It's hard to say for sure though given I can't see the full context of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me with this! Both of those formulas work but I had some difficulty filtering by a boolean condition so I ended up going with the COUNTROWS solution. How would one filter on a boolean condition to only show the "true" rows?

Comment: [First Instance?] returns a boolean, so you could write e.g. FILTER ( TableName, [First Instance?] ).